# Transient duration for cholestorol medication

Tags: cholesterol, triglycerides

I understand that triglycerides levels are modulated / reduced by

1. diet
2. medications

Assuming diet is not changed, and a very high (400+ mg / DL) is reduced to 150. How long (order of magnitude: 3 hours, 3 days, 3 weeks, months?) does it take to reach a steady state of 150?  Assume crestor and fenofibrate are the cholesterol meds.

Comment: I'm not sure this can be answered.  Assuming the 400 is a true fasting TRG (as TRG is dramatically affected by food intake), such a dramatic reduction would vary very widely based on individual factors, from weeks to months to years - and unfortunately, without diet/exercise changes, such a high TRG is likely to never normalize on meds alone.  Meanwhile, I have witnessed over 50% reduction in true fasting TRG within one week at an inpatient lifestyle medicine program using just exercise and a properly balanced whole-food plant-based diet. Exercise and diet are CRITICAL in lipid metabolism.

Comment: My comment about the inpatient lifestyle med setting just is to illustrate that I've seen with my own eyes what is possible in such a short time frame by following strict lifestyle medicine principles.  The literature is clear that it works at home as well, as long as it is done right.  https://lifestylemedicine.org/ACLM/Lifestyle_Medicine/Scientific_Evidence/ACLM/About/What_is_Lifestyle_Medicine_/Scientific_Evidence.aspx?hkey=ed4b4130-6ce9-41bb-8703-211bc98eed7f